# (NEWBIE) I want to predict 3 variables using machine learning, my current code errors out and I have no clue what to do

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning

I am relatively new to machine learning and I would like to predict the 3 different variables at the same time from this spreadsheet which will become a csv file
[image]

my code currently looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression


data = pd.read_csv("weight-reps-volume-data.csv")


X = data[['prev_weight', 'prev_reps', 'prev_volume']]
y = data[['weight', 'reps', 'volume']]


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

predictions = model.predict(X_test)
print(predictions)
```

i have no clue where to start debugging this, or if im doing the right thing any help would be appreciated

as said above i would like to predict all 3 variables at the same time if i ask the algorithm for a prediction for example its output would be (90,10,900)

Comment: To receive debugging help, always include the full error traceback output, in text format.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `sklearn.multioutput` to work with multiple linear regression. Something like below probably will work for you.

A similar example which has three targets(dependent variable) and rest are independent features are presented below. You can can check the datasets by printing them or you can use .shape to check their dimensions. Note I am not doing any splits here, but you should follow your train_test_split mechanism. I am just proposing here the way out for your situation. Thanks

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_linnerud ## Inbuilt datasets
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputRegressor
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
X, y = load_linnerud(return_X_y=True) ## y has 3 target similar to your input file
lr = LinearRegression() ## Instance of linear regression
model = MultiOutputRegressor(lr).fit(X, y) ## fit after applying it to MUltiOutputRegressor
model.predict(X)
```